# Sublime text problem (javac: invalid flag:)

Tags: java, sublimetext3, javac

I have installed Sublime Text 3 to code in Java. I have followed a video to do it. I did all the steps as shown on the video but when i try to compile it does not work.

[image: hello World and error]

I have the jdk here:

[image: jdk and jde]

and I added the jdk 1.8.0 here:

[image: path]

I don't know what have I done wrong... pls help :D

Comment: When diagnosing build problems in Sublime, it's important to include the `sublime-build` that you're using; otherwise we can't tell why things are not working. That said, in the image above the tab has the name `untitled`, which seems to indicate that you didn't save the file before you tried to build it. So I'd try doing that first and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

java path is properly configured since it's found the compiler `javac`.

Error said that `javac` it's not properly invoked. 

Basic compilation and run steps are:

( on the same level as `MainClass` - `HelloMundo`)

`javac HelloMundo.java` (1_compile) and after

`java HelloMundo` (2_run) ### this will run if try directly from console 


Also, save the file first with `class name`, in your case `HelloMundo.java`

Maybe it's better to search also for further documentation and even take a look of how to add properly the pictures. Good Luck !